# ¿Por qué una "idea de bombero" es una idea descabellada o absurda?

Tags: etimología, modismos, españa

En el epígrafe [**bombero**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5pfRKTI) del Diccionario de la Lengua se recoge:

> de bombero
>
> 1. loc. adj. coloq. *Esp.* Dicho de algo como una idea o un comportamiento: Descabellado, absurdo.

He visto la expresión "idea de bombero" con ese significado, pero no veo una clara relación con el significado de "descabellado, absurdo" que tiene.

Answer (score 3):

[Ya está el listo que todo lo sabe](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-tener-ideas-de-bombero/) nos saca de dudas, como siempre. En su artículo *¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión ‘Tener ideas de bombero’?*, comenta:

> Cuando alguien tiene una ocurrencia algo estrambótica y fuera de lo común se suele utilizar la expresión “tienes ideas de bombero” e incluso para enfatizar más lo absurdo del asunto se llega a decir “tienes ideas de bombero jubilado/retirado”.
>
> Hoy en día cuando se te quedan las llaves dentro de casa llamas a un cerrajero, para un escape de agua a un fontanero o si se ha petado el diferencial de la luz a un electricista… para cada problema tenemos un especialista a quien recurrir.
>
> Pero hubo un tiempo en el que el cuerpo de bomberos no solo era avisado para que acudiese a sofocar un fuego, sino que lo llamaban para solventar cualquier otro tipo de problema… a veces de lo más doméstico. Habituales son las imágenes en las que aparecen subiendo a un árbol para coger a un lindo gatito, rescatar a alguien que se ha quedado atascado en un ascensor, etc…
>
> Ese era el motivo por el que la unidad se componía no solo de personas especializadas en apagar incendios, sino por otras que también dominaban múltiples facetas profesionales (cerrajería, electricidad, fontanería, albañilería…).
>
> Muy a menudo tenían que echar mano de su ingenio para solventar el problema por el que había sido requerido sus servicios y evidentemente esas ideas, a pesar de ser estrambóticas, resultaban efectivas.
>
> Esa habilidad por resolver cualquier problema o incidencia mediante ocurrencias que podían resultar extravagantes llevó a que se popularizara esta famosa expresión.

Me parece curiosa esta razón, pues con el tiempo *tener ideas de bombero* se ha acabado ridiculizando, tomando una connotación de ideas raras o incluso malas, cuando su explicación sugiere que la idea mala fue del que precisó de la ayuda del bombero.

Comment: @walen pues tienes razón y siempre había creído estas entradas a pies juntillas.

Answer (score 3):

Un bombero es un técnico de rescate y emergencias, por lo que sus actuaciones priorizan salvar vidas y evitar males mayores frente a minimizar daños. Así, una actuación típica de un bombero sería tirar una puerta para rescatar a alguien. Cuando esta manera de pensar se aplica fuera de una situación de emergencia se dice que es una "idea de bombero jubilado".